# Print debug stack trace (within block)

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, twig, pimcore

Trying to extend a formbuilder plugin for Pimcore (https://github.com/dachcom-digital/pimcore-formbuilder) I am trying to modify the output of input/select fields in order to be compatible with MD Bootstrap syntax.

Therefore I override `/FormBuilderBundle/Form/Theme/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig`. The shortened content of this file is like this:

```
{% extends 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' %}

{% use '@FormBuilder/Form/Theme/Type/dynamic_multi_file.html.twig' %}
{% use '@FormBuilder/Form/Theme/Type/html_tag.html.twig' %}
{% use '@FormBuilder/Form/Theme/Type/snippet.html.twig' %}
{% use '@FormBuilder/Form/Theme/Type/container.html.twig' %}

{% block form_row -%}
    {% set form_row_class = attr['data-template'] is defined ? attr['data-template'] : 'col-12' %}
    {% if form.vars.is_form_builder_container_block is defined %}
        {% set form_row_class = 'formbuilder-container-block' %}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="formbuilder-row md-form {{ form_row_class }}">
        {{ parent() }}
    </div>
{%- endblock form_row %}
```

The problem is that there is no other file called `bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig` (except in the macros folder) and the template can not extend itself. I want to find out what the `parent()` function is doing here in order to alter the output (https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/parent.html).

As I still did not find the template which is extended I would like to print the parent() functions' stack trace in order to know which files are involved. Is there any possibility to do this with Twig (maybe with a Twig Extension)?

Comment: If I remember, twig will compile/generate a .php file somewhere, with actual php code, where you can edit and debug as you wish, with xdebug or other way (var_dump, ...).

Comment: The `parent()` function, in this case will call/output the default content that is inside the block definition `form_row` of the file `bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig`. So the giving code just will wrap an extra `div` arround the default output of that said template

Comment: @DarkBee You are right. Thx.